# SQL query if status of customer change, if status not change then no records require

Tags: sql, teradata

[image] Picture added for table and output below is the table structure id , status and datechange

| id | st | chngdt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 01-07-2022 |
| 123 | 1 | 02-07-2022 |
| 123 | 1 | 03-07-2022 |
| 123 | 1 | 01-07-2022 |
| 145 | 1 | 05-07-2022 |
| 156 | 1 | 01-07-2022 |
| 156 | 1 | 02-07-2022 |
| 156 | 2 | 06-07-2022 |
| 156 | 3 | 09-07-2022 |

Need output if customer status change only:

| id | oldsts | old_date | New_st | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 156 | 2 | 06-07-2022 | 3 | 09-07-2022 |

Looking for SQL or Teradata query

Comment: SQL or Teradata? Teradata supports SQL.

Comment: Why not also the status `2` record, with the change from `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, st As new_st, chngdt As [date]
        ,LAG(st) OVER (partition by id order by chngdt) oldsts
        ,LAG(chngdt) OVER (partition by id order by chngdt) old_date
    FROM [table]
) t
WHERE oldsts <> st and oldsts is not null
```

Though I may have the order backwards, where you need a `DESC`.

See here for more info about `Lag()` and other windowing functions:

> https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/148t/functions/window.html

If you really only want the last record for each id, you can also do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, st As new_st, chngdt As [date]
        ,LAG(st) OVER (partition by id order by chngdt) oldsts
        ,LAG(chngdt) OVER (partition by id order by chngdt) old_date
    FROM [table]
) t
WHERE oldsts <> st and oldsts is not null
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by id order by st desc) = 1
```

More info on `QUALIFY`:

> https://www.teradatapoint.com/teradata/qualify-clause-in-teradata.htm